# Can you make your own guitar capo with things around the house?

Tags: guitar

I have lost my capo. Does anybody know of any easy DIY guitar capos one can make from items around the house?

Comment: WWM[cGyver]D ?   me, I'd waste hours designing one in CAD and 3D printing it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plastic pen (parallel sided), a bolt inside plastic tubing, short length of dowling, rubber band for tension, a scrunchie can work, maybe with an eraser behind the neck for more tension.

Works better on flat or large radius fingerboards.

The ubiquitous index finger has also been used on occasions...

Answer (score 4):

A pencil and an elastic band is a classic.

Wikipedia demos one at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guitar/Guitar_Accessories

[image: capo made from a pencil]
Attribution: [Lovenotmakewar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Lovenotmakewar) at [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/)

Comment: wouldn't that wear out the strings?

Comment: If you keep the same set on for years, possibly!

Answer (score 1):

any flat object that's not to big around.ie 1/4 " tree branch and to keep it in place any string tied at each end keepinp it tight to the neck.I have done this while camping out.i also made drum sticks from tree branches

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of things, the fastest is to look it up on  [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/howto/Guitar+capo).
Besides the pencil and rubber band, there are also capos that need more effort to make:

[image]